# Where to run neo4j spatial queries and code?

Tags: neo4j, spatial

Beeing till now a RDBMS user its difficult for me to understand the interface of neo4j server when it comes using spatial plugin.
I am used to the interfaces of oracle spatial and postgis in which someone can use the provided gui to create a table with geometry etc. 
I have two questions. 
1) How can I create a node in neo4j server (I am using version 1.9) with spatial features (coordinates)I read the manual from here:

```
      http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/
```

and I know that I have to create a spatial index, then create a node and later to add the node to the index. But doing this through the console of neo4j 1.9 is not efficient. Is there an interface which I can use to do this?

2) In this website: http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/#spatial-import-shapefile 
they show a way to import shapefiles in neo4j. What I don't understand (might besimple but as I said all these things are new to me) is where should I execute this code.

```
     GraphDatabaseService database = new EmbeddedGraphDatabase(databasePath);
       try {
         ShapefileImporter importer = new ShapefileImporter(database);
         importer.importFile("shp/highway.shp", "highway", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
     } finally {
         database.shutdown();
     }
```

Although neo4j and its spatial extension is very promising and interesting I think the community is very small and the existing examples very few. I hope I get some help.

Thank you.
D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a very clear explanation I kindly suggest you to visit this post: http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/03/10/neo4jcypher-finding-football-stadiums-near-a-city-using-spatial/

All you have to do is adding a property to your nodes as for example: { "wtk": "POINT(-2.20024 53.483)" }. If you're familiar with java or some other language you could implement a small piece of code to create these nodes and add them to the index, as Mark did.

I also wrote something on my blog: http://inserpio.wordpress.com/2014/04/03/artworks-spatial-search/

Once again, the code you pasted have to be execute as a simple java program that connects to the graph db and import shape files with a well-known format.

Finally you'll be able to inquiry your node by executing Cypher queries like:

start m=node:museumLocation('withinDistance:[51.5086,-0.1283,0.1]') return m;

where "museumLocation" is the index name, (51.5086,-0.1283) is the center of a circle, 0.1 is the radius within it you want to find some museums.

Cheers,
Lorenzo

Comment: Thanks for your answer inserpio. I read a lot of different things online. In some websites they say I have to use Maven and some others use Gephi software. I have never worked with any of them. Are they necessary to use them (especially Maven)? Also, you mean I have to use an IDE like Eclipse for Java to run the code I pasted? Thanks.

Comment: If you want to avoid using some language you could only use the neo4j browser to load your data via the Cypher statement LOAD CSV, which takes data from a comma separated values file. Once your DB is populated, it depends what you want to achieve: for complex rendering you should select a proper graph visualisation tool. Gephi is good and you can read something about it here: http://bit.ly/1Bcucfo. Many other graph visualisation tools exist: Linkurious is another great tool. Let me just understand a little bit better your needs so that I can help you!

Comment: I will try to describe what I want to do. My final aim is to manage to add geometrical character to existing nodes of a database, which have not a spatial character. I want to do this using a language which access the neo4j and modify their properties and their relationships (add spatial part) so later I can run spatial queries using these nodes. But I guess the most important question is if I can give to an existing node the spatial character. Is this possible? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes it's definitely possible: just add a prop which hosts the spatial character (i.e. POINT(-2.20024 53.483)). If you have a huge db it won't be possible to add this prop by hand so we have to automate via LOAD CSV. Suppose we want to add geospatial data to each museum node, which are unique by name.

Create a file "museum_spatial.csv":

MUSEUM, COORDS
National Gallery, POINT( -0.1283 51.5086 )
The Museum of Modern Art, POINT( -73.977664 40.761484 )

and load it via Cypher:

LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS "museum_spatial.csv" as csvLine
MATCH (m) WHERE m.name = csvLine.MUSEUM
SET m.wkt = csvLine.COORDS

Comment: So first I have to create some nodes in neo4j with the names of the museums. Then create a csv file with this format (the coordinates have to be like you provide or in comma seperated values like: museum_name, lat, lon?) And then use the data browser in neo4j to load the CSV. The query you gave me actually will do the matching with the existing museum nodes? And create also the relationships with the spatial index?

Comment: You can create 'lat' and 'lon' props as well. No, you have to add nodes to the spatial index via REST API: http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/spatial/#rest-api-add-a-node-to-the-spatial-index. In the end, a small portion of java code could really simplify the load part, then you can finally run on the browser simple queries like this: start m=node:museumLocation('withinDistance:[51.5086,-0.1283,0.1]') return m

Comment: Hi insperio, I was wondering if you can give me an advice with something regarding the java code I have paster above. I haven't worked with java in the past. Should I use eclipse to create a new project and a new class and use the pasted code? I have downloaded and installed with maven the spatial library but what am I supposed to do to make this snipper of code run?

Comment: Hi dkar, sure! Maybe it's better if we move to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/neo4j so that we can have a better conversation. Please post again your question there and I'll be happy to help you. Lorenzo